# Transform ASCII Art to OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I've recently started to work on a small project that consist of getting my camera input and transforming it into a virtual camera output as an Ascii art.

In order to do so, I've decided to use OpenCV to get my camera input and v4l2loopback for the virtual camera output.

In between, I've made a simple program that transform my OpenCV Mat into a grayscale Mat and then  a function that transform my grayscale mat into an Ascii art

Unfortunately I've found myself stuck at the moment where i want to transform my Ascii art into a new mat.
I've had a look at [openCV putText function source code (l.2256)](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp) in order to reproduce the same effect myself but I'm not able to fully understand it.

[Here](https://github.com/Guerout-Arnaud/ascii-webcam/tree/ae5de9020a0d59cb347ee29b15d624031cacc97c) is a sample code if you want to try some thing on your own (Make sure to have openCV installed)

If anyone has an idea on how to do so I would really appreciate the help. Also, this is just a POC to learn how to do so, I do plan to rework it.

Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks by advance.

Comment: Let me see if I understand the problem. You have an array of ASCII characters that is the representation of an image. You want to convert this array into an OpenCV `Mat`. However, you are not sure how to map the ASCII array to the OpenCV `Mat`, right?

Comment: Yeah this is exactly my problem. 
From your answer i fell like i'm missing something really obvious do i ? 
If i do i'm sorry this is my first time using openCV

Comment: Don’t worry, man, the problem is not trivial. The thing is that `Mat`s only store numbers. I suppose you would want an actual image of the array of the ASCII characters, rather than a character matrix. You’d need to first “render” the ASCII array into a raster (made by pixels) image. Maybe you can render each character using `putText` one by one. Render each character as a “cell” and stitch each cell into a big `Mat`, just like if they were pixels, but rather than pixels they are "cells" containing a rasterized character made by `putText`.

Comment: So if i understand correctly you suggest that i create a new `Mat`on which i use `putText` then store the "mask" of the ascii char to build a new `Mat` from my array ?

Comment: yeah, that's the idea

Comment: Ok, i'll give it a try tomorrow (it's 1am rn for me) and i'll let you know. 
an other idea i've got would be to map, in the software, the characters themselves 
do you think this could be a possibility ? (if you've looked at the sample provided you may have seen that i only use few char, not event 10 differents)
Thanks for your help really appreciate it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a small proof of concept for converting a `char` matrix into an OpenCV `Mat`, using `cv::putText`. The idea is that you start with a matrix of `char`s (here, defined using `std::vector`) and you loop through each item. You extract the `char`, create a *cell* (an empty BGR `Mat` with a defined size), and you *concatenate* each cell into a bigger `Mat`. First you create columns (horizontal concatenation) and then you create rows (vertical concatenation), here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{

    // Create a test matrix of characters:
    std::vector< std::vector<char> > charMatrix;
    charMatrix.push_back( {'O', 'F', 'O'} );
    charMatrix.push_back( {'F', 'F', 'F'} );
    charMatrix.push_back( {'O', 'F', 'O'} );

    // Get the char matrix dimensions:
    int charMatCols = charMatrix[0].size();
    int charMatRows = charMatrix.size();

    // Define the cell dimensions:
    int cellWidth = 64;
    int cellHeight = 64;

    // Define the output matrix:
    cv::Mat outputMatrix;


    // Loop thru the char matrix:
    for ( int i = 0; i < charMatRows; i++ ){

        // Get current row:
        std::vector<char> currentRow = charMatrix[i];

        // Temp mat to store each row:
        cv::Mat rowMat;

        // Process each character on current row:
        for ( int j = 0; j < charMatCols; j++ ){

            // Get current char:
            char currentChar = currentRow[j];

            // Create cell:
            cv::Mat currentCell = cv::Mat::zeros( cellHeight, cellWidth, CV_8UC3 );
            // Set text properties:
            cv::Point textPosition(10,50);
            cv::Scalar textColor(0,255,0);
            int textSize = 2;

            // char to std::string:
            std::string cellChar(1, currentChar);

            // Put text on cell
            cv::putText( currentCell, cellChar, textPosition, 
                         cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, textSize, textColor, 1, cv::LINE_8, false );

            // Concatenate current cell mat: to current row mat:
            if ( j == 0 ){
                // First time there's no previous mat
                rowMat = currentCell;
            }else{
                // Concatenate after first cell is processed:
                cv::hconcat( currentCell, rowMat, rowMat );
            }

        }

        // Concatenate current row into previous row:
        if ( i == 0 ){
            outputMatrix = rowMat;
        }else{
            cv::vconcat( rowMat, outputMatrix, outputMatrix );
        }

    }

    // show the output mat:
    cv::imshow( "outputMatrix", outputMatrix );
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the input char matrix:

```
'O', 'F', 'O'
'F', 'F', 'F'
'O', 'F', 'O'
```

And this is the output image:

[image]

You'll notice that I'm using Opencv's `hconcat` and `vconcat` to concatenate a `Mat` to a `Mat` horizontally and then vertically. The characters are off-center because I pretty much guessed their position to be *approximately* at the center of each cell. You could define the text `size` and `position` as a function of the cell dimensions, but you would need to calculate each glyph's dimensions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, really appreciate it
Unfortunately i'm getting rid of openCV for this projet but 100 %  sure this can help for future projects and for other users :D

Comment: @Dzious No problem, man. Hopefully you will find OpenCV more useful in another context, cheers!